# Grafting apple onto mango

Tags: apples, grafting

I'm wondering if I graft an apple root stock onto mango, will it work and what would be the results? Will it survive the UK winters?

Comment: Rootstocks are not **grafted onto** other material. The scion is grafted on the stock. Bottom up.

Answer (score 6):

Grafting an apple rootstock onto a mango is unlikely to succeed due to significant genetic differences between the two species. Even if the grafting were technically possible, the mango part would not survive UK winters, as mango trees require a tropical or subtropical climate. For growing tropical fruits like mangoes in the UK, using a greenhouse or focusing on fruit varieties suitable for the temperate climate would be more practical.